# How to delete the selected words in the text?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, if-statement

This code selects words and makes an array from them. But I need to delete words after being selected and added to the array. I think I need to work with either document.getSelection() or document.selection, but I don't know how to delete the selected words through them. I would be happy if anyone gave me a hint.

```
<script>
let container;
var arr = [];
function get_selection() {
  
    var txt = '';
       if (document.getSelection) {
          txt = document.getSelection().toString();
                
                
            } 

            else if (document.selection) {
                txt = document.selection.createRange().text;
            }
             arr.push(txt);
            }
            }
           document.getElementById("txt").onclick = get_selection;

</script>
```

Comment: did this words/text are in textarea ?

Comment: It can be textarea, but I am using div contenteditable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [onselect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onselect) event. on element or just global but then you have to figure out that your target is not eg. menu element :P. Then you can use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/Element/textContent) if you use contenteditable and just substring value before selection and after it and set content value to sum of it. I use textarea, using contenteditable in most cases is not best practice.

```js
const selections = []

const handleOnSelect = (e) =>{
  const target = e.target;
  const start = target.selectionStart;
  const end = target.selectionEnd;
  const selection = target.value.substring(start, end);
  selections.push(selection);
  const pre = target.value.substring(0 , start);
  const post = target.value.substring(end);
  target.value = pre + post;
  
  console.log(selections)
}


window.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
   const target = document.getElementById("txt")
   target.addEventListener("select", handleOnSelect);
})
```

```html
<textarea id="txt"> </textarea>
```

Comment: @NikN would be nice if you mark my answer as best one :)